# React-native taking over 150-200% of computers CPU

Tags: react-native, webpack, redux, webpack-dev-server

I've been having a problem where when I run my `React-native` APP in xCode it starts to use `150%` of my CPU. This is insane! I've got no idea why as well? I'm using webpack to convert my babel into react.

Here are all the my modules:

```
"scripts": {
    "android-setup-port": "adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8080",
    "start": "env NODE_ENV=DEV rnws start --hostname localhost",
    "build": "env NODE_ENV=PRODUCTION rnws bundle",
    "test": "eslint src",
    "debugger-replace": "remotedev-debugger-replace --hostname localhost --port 5678",
    "remotedev": "npm run debugger-replace && remotedev --hostname localhost --port 5678"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=4",
    "npm": ">=2 <4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@exponent/react-native-navigator": "^0.4.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "immutable": "^3.7.5",
    "react-native": "^0.19.0",
    "react-native-button": "^1.3.1",
    "react-native-form": "^1.0.6",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^1.1.6",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.3.0",
    "react-redux": "^4.0.6",
    "redux": "^3.0.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^1.0.3",
    "tcomb-form-native": "^0.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.3.17",
    "babel-eslint": "^5.0.0-beta6",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.3.13",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.5",
    "eslint": "^1.10.3",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^3.11.2",
    "react-native-webpack-server": "^0.8.3",
    "remote-redux-devtools": "0.0.10",
    "remote-redux-devtools-on-debugger": "^0.2.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.0"
  }
```

Here is my webpack config:

```
var path = require('path'),
    webpack = require('webpack'),
    Clean = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
   // {
   //              test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
   //              loaders: [
   //                  'url?limit=8192',
   //                  'img'
   //              ]
   //          },
var dev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'DEV' ? true : false,
    production = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'PRODUCTION' ? true : false;

module.exports =  {
    // debug: false,
    // devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: {
        'index.ios': ['./src/index.jsx'],
        'index.android': ['./src/index.jsx'],

    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '__build__'),
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
        { test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$/i, loader: "file-loader" },
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$|\.js?$/,
            include: [
                path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
                path.resolve(__dirname, './config'),
                path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native'),
                path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/react-native-navbar'),
                // path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/react-native-maps'),
                path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/react-native-google-places-autocomplete'),
                path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/@exponent'),
                path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/react-clone-referenced-element')
            ],
            loader: 'babel',
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react']
            },
        },

        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
        modulesDirectories: [
            'node_modules',
            './config',
            './src/',
            './src/components',
            './src/layouts',
            './src/scripts/',
            './src/scripts/actions/',
            './src/scripts/api/',
            './src/scripts/containers/',
            './src/scripts/reducers/'
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            __PROD__  : production,
            __DEV__   : dev
        })
    ].concat(production ? [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
        new Clean(['__build__'])
    ] : [])
};
```

Has anyone got an idea to why this is happening? I've searched all over google to find a solution but can't!

#### Update 1:

I have not solved this yet. But instead of running a `Simulator`, I have connected my `iPhone` to act as the `device`. At least this takes the stress off my `CPU`.

#### Update 2:

So as I was developing I took a blind eye to this issue as I didn't want to spend too long debugging it. I think the issue was to do with requiring un-needed files, using for loops on objects instead of having objects in an array and mapping them using `.map(`, changing `var` to `const` and `let`, updating my react-code to comply with `es6 standards`.

This helped a lot! The `CPU` usage went down and was running normally.

#### Update 3:

**update 2** did help out a lot. But I've found another reason why my `CPU` is getting throttled. When enabling `live reload` my `CPU` usage jumped straight to `150+%` and my computer fan starting running real hot.

The weird thing is my `live reload` never actually worked? But anyway hope this helps!

Comment: +1 having this issue of 150% cpu usage, but not using react-native. The CPU was fine with everything similar to what you have, but then spiked once I added Babel to the project. From what I gather Babel loads everything into memory - still trying to figure out the solution. The react-start-kit doesn't have this issue: https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit

Comment: @mummybot - Interesting. I think it must've been some sort of infinite loop or something. I just ignored the issue and as I developed my app further the issue disappeared! +1 my question if ya wanna ;)

Comment: So I figured mine out too. I was running the webpack dev server for static assets and a separate livereload server for PHP only. Unfortunately the combination of the two in my setup seemed to "blow up", I'm probably not isolating the watched PHP files well enough for the livereload server and sending the page into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally found out why this was happening. It has something todo with the `live reload` feature that the simulator offers.

When this was activated, instantly my computer `CPU` jumped to `150+%`. Now I'm not sure why this is happening? Another thing I should add is that my `live reload` never actually worked, maybe I've not set something up right or something.

Anyway, hope this helps! If anyone could confirm or replicate this issue and get back to me that'd be great! I reported an issue on github: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6752

Just `disable live reload`.